# I am getting error "TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE" when using PHP SAP RFC reading table data

Tags: php, saprfc

Below is my code :
I am able to connect to SAP system and when I am trying to read data from table I am getting below exception. Please any one can help me to figure out the issue. 
Error message : {success:false, msg: 'Exception raised: TABLE_NOT_AVAILABLE'}

```
$fce = saprfc_function_discover($rfc, "SAPMOdule"); 
if (! $fce ){
    echo "{success: false, msg: 'Discovering interface of function module  failed'}";
    exit;
}
 saprfc_table_init ($fce,"TableName"); 
 saprfc_import ($fce,"Column1",'0602');
 saprfc_import ($fce,"Column2",'ZA00');
set_time_limit ( 0 );

$rfc_rc = saprfc_call_and_receive ($fce);

if ($rfc_rc != SAPRFC_OK){
    if ($rfc_rc == SAPRFC_EXCEPTION ){
        ExitRFC($rfc, $fce, "false", "Exception raised: " . saprfc_exception($fce));
    }else{
        ExitRFC($rfc, $fce, "false", "Call error: " . saprfc_error($fce));
    }
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the table you are trying to read, is not yet activated in the ABAP DDIC. For more details see my answer to this question:
[Table_not_available when using JAVA SAP RFC_READ_TABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44806332/table-not-available-when-using-java-sap-rfc-read-table)

(Just replace the name "LTAP" with the name of your table.)

Answer (score 0):

Often databases require a *domainname.tablename* instead of only *tablename*. I don't know about SAP.